# Simplifying C++ callbacks statically

Tags: c++, templates, callback

When you use callback methods in your code, normally you know what is the callback to be called at the compile time. Is there anyway to optimize these callbacks at compile time?

Comment: Actually, normally you don't know. You need to consider that "normal" is across *all* possible C++ code, not just heavy use of templates. A good old library written to accept a function pointer and `void*`... or even just a `std::function`... cannot "know".

Comment: @StoryTeller-UnslanderMonica True, from normally, I meant when I needed to design a library/code with callbacks in C++ code.

Comment: Standard example: `std::sort` - so you can use templates to achieve this goal. IMO question is to general and need more focus.

Comment: Let the compiler do this kind of optimisations. If it can, it will. If it can't, you probably can't either.

Comment: @MarekR callback in `std::sort` is called via argument. please check my idea in the answer.

Comment: @n.1.8e9-where's-my-sharem. please my idea is in my own answer.

Comment: "I have searched internet and I didn't see anyone writing their callbacks like this". The entire C++ standard library is specified to use callbacks like this. You seem to be under an impression that because say `std::sort` uses a regular function argument, it cannot optimise the call away. This impression is wrong, it can and does that very well.

Answer (score 0):

When you write a code, there are several cases that you need to use callbacks in your code. A famous example is the [observer pattern](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Observer_pattern). In general, codes are based on ideas like this:

```
template<typename FN>
void run_callback_legacy(FN fn) {
    fn();
}

void foo() {
    std::cout << "foo\n";
}

int main() {
    run_callback_legacy(foo);
}
```

In this case, you can save function pointer `fn` in a variable(such as `std::function`) and call it later too.

But when you use callbacks a lot, you notice that callbacks you set are **normally fixed in your code at compile time**. You rarely need to dynamically specify your callback at runtime. I always thought that if the callback that I need to use is fixed during compile time, why I need to set it through a function like a argument? It didn't feel right, but I didn't want to call functions directly because I lose reusability of my code. I needed a way to set callback functions statically at compile time.

After trying several times, I finally found that my idea is possible using templates. You can statically define your callback via **template arguments**, not method arguments. I have searched internet and I didn't see anyone writing their callbacks like this(There may be some, but I didn't find any). Anyway, I decided to share this way of writing callbacks with you. It may be strange at first, but I personally like it more than passing callback methods as function arguments:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <functional>
#include <type_traits>

void foo() {
    std::cout << "foo\n";
}

void goo(int i) {
    std::cout << "goo: " << i << "\n";
}

template<auto Callback, typename... Args>
void run_callback(Args&&... args) {
    std::invoke(Callback, std::forward<Args>(args)...);
}

struct Simple {
    void goo(int i) {
        std::cout << "Simple goo: " << i << "\n";
    }
};

template<auto Callback>
class Complex {
public:
    Complex() : callback_(Callback) {};

    template<typename... Args>
    void run_later(Args&&... args) {
        std::invoke(callback_, std::forward<Args>(args)...);
    }

private:
    decltype(Callback) callback_;
};

int main() {
    // Simple non-member
    run_callback<foo>();
    run_callback<goo>(1);

    // Simple member
    Simple s;
    run_callback<&Simple::goo>(s, 2);

    // Call later
    Complex<foo> complex_foo;
    complex_foo.run_later();

    Complex<&Simple::goo> complex_foo2;
    complex_foo2.run_later(s, 3);
}
```

There are 3 different callbacks in this example:

1. Simple callback to non class-member function
2. Simple callback to class-member function
3. A more complex callback that is called later, can be used as a base for observer pattern

As you see, You practically pass your callback as template argument, so you don't need to pass them as arguments anymore. In addition, since everything is resolved statically, this code may(?) run quicker than a normal callback.

I will be happy to hear your thought about this method.

Comment: *since everything is resolved statically, this code may(?) run quicker than a normal callback* You should probably go benchmark it. You will most likely gain nothing except more boilerplate.